# Android Studio Emulator not starting

Tags: android, android-emulator

Because the emulator was really slow I installed the intel x86 emulator. I changed the settings in my emulator (ARM to intel atom). Now when I run a project it takes me to the emulator selection screen and when I select it, the project starts running, but the emulator doesn't pop up.

I tried switching the cpu back to ARM, but it still doesn't work.

When I close Android studio it asks me if I want to disconnect from the project so I'm sure it is running. 
I came across a few  posts that said to give the device 768 ram, but that didn't work.

Anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the exact same issue, but for me reducing the device RAM to 768 did fix it. Therefore I'd suggest continuing to decrease the RAM values and trying to launch it.

Answer (score 2):

How about to use [Rock speed Emulator - Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)?

I know it sometimes take time to launch emulator and launch app in emulator too. But it depends on your configuration of your PC and settings you have done in Eclipse or Android Studio.

For example: You may have kept "Build Automatically" ON and it sometimes slow down running time.

Answer (score 1):

My current rep is not high enough yet to comment on another answer, so I am adding a new "answer" to +1 Paresh Mayani's answer to use Genymotion.  I only recently discovered it and found it to be much much faster than the emulator.  Instead of emulation it runs an Android rom in a VM using VirtualBox.  I've found that it runs full speed on my machine and is just as fast in debug mode as normal mode, which is impressive since even my Nexus 5 struggles when connected to a debugger.

Comment: Yeah its faster as it runs Android OS (ROM) in a virtual environment using VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

In my case also x86 was creating problem, I installed Android 5.0.1 armeabi-v7a and have set 768MB as RAM size and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check and run the emulator ie. store a snapshot for faster startup...
I have tried that by checking the button and works fine.
[image: See the image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an AMD machine try using the "ARM EABI v7 system image". For an intel chip use the "APIs Intelx86 Atom system image". Also, try a different tablet from the Android Studio settings e.g(Nexus 6), as the API level might not be supported from in the Nexus5 VM. You will also have a little wait time for the android emulator, mine takes about 7mins