# "HelloWorld" app not visible on Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android development and I am using **Android Studio**.
I just created a new project which contains "**HelloWorld**" by default and ran the project.
I am able to get a virtual Nexus device on screen, but it does not shows my app on it, i.e., "HelloWorld" is not visible.

In the "**run**" tab, it shows the following message:

> C:\Users\Vishal\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd
>   Nexus_4_API_22 -netspeed full -netdelay none
>
> emulator: device fd:860
>
> HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
>
> creating window 40 81 335 557
>
> emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

**Note**: The project was built without errors.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Why dont you use a real device?

Comment: Did you unlock the screen of your virtual device?

Comment: Yes I unlocked the device too.

Comment: do not use avd, it is much worser then emulator from genymotion - https://www.genymotion.com/#!/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following; Close the existing emulator and in the run tab, switch onto the app pane (the messages that you have posted in the question appears on the device pane) Click on the red button on the left hand side panel to stop your application. Once it has stopped, click on the green arrow to run your application again. (Be patient, it might take a while :) )

If this is successful, you should see messages indicating that your application was installed onto the device.

Also you can try decreasing the device RAM to 768 as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978403/android-studio-emulator-not-starting)